# how to keep the duplicates in the result of group by

Tags: mysql

I have written this query to get records where seats are maximum for each assembly, but this query is removing duplicates from the result:

**Query:**

```
select * from (select assembly, party_id, count(party_id) as seats from winner
group by assembly, party_id) as subTable group by assembly having max(seats) order by assembly asc;
```

**Output:**

[image]

**But I want the output to be like this:**

[image]

please tell what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what the `having` clause is for.  It is just checking that the maximum is not equal to 0.

You need to group by the `party_id`.  I think this is what you want:

```
select assembly, party_id, count(party_id) as seats
from winner
group by assembly, party_id
order by assembly asc;
```

Comment: I just want to keep the duplicates in the result, but group clause is removing the duplicates

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the duplicate assemblies, don't use `GROUP BY assembly,` whose function is to remove the duplicates.

Strange question.